# How to paint with alpha?

Tags: android

I want to paint graphics onto a Canvas such that the colors are additive. For example, I want to produce this:
[image: Proper additive colors]

But instead, I get this:
[image: My results]

Note that the half white, half black background is intentional, just to see how alpha interacts with both backgrounds. I will be happy to have this work with either background. Here is my code:

```
public class VennColorsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        class VennView extends View {
            public VennView(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                int alpha = 60, val = 255;
                int ar = Color.argb(alpha, val, 0, 0);
                int ag = Color.argb(alpha, 0, val, 0);
                int ab = Color.argb(alpha, 0, 0, val);
                float w = canvas.getWidth();
                float h = canvas.getHeight();
                float cx = w / 2f;
                float cy = h / 2;
                float r = w / 5;
                float tx = (float) (r * Math.cos(30 * Math.PI / 180));
                float ty = (float) (r * Math.sin(30 * Math.PI / 180));
                float expand = 1.5f;
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, (int) w, (int) (h / 2)), paint);
                PorterDuff.Mode mode = android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.ADD;
                paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ar, mode));
                paint.setColor(ar);
                canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy - r, expand * r, paint);
                paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ag, mode));
                paint.setColor(ag);
                canvas.drawCircle(cx - tx, cy + ty, expand * r, paint);
                paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ab, mode));
                paint.setColor(ab);
                canvas.drawCircle(cx + tx, cy + ty, expand * r, paint);
            }
        }
        this.setContentView(new VennView(this));
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me understand how to paint with additive colors in Android graphics?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are on the right track. There are 3 major issues in your code:

- You need to set xfer mode iso color filter
- Use temp bitmap for rendering your image
- Alpha should be 0xFF in order to get results you are looking for

Here is what I've got by using xfer mode. What I'm doing - is drawing everything into temporary bitmap and then rendering entire bitmap to main canvas.

[image: xfer mode rules]

You ask why do you need temp bitmap? Good question! If you are drawing everything on a main canvas, your colors will be blended with main canvas background color, so all colors will get messed up. Transparent temp bitmap helps to keep your colors away of other parts of UI

Please make sure you are not allocating anything in `onDraw()` - you will run out memory very soon in this way.. Also make sure you have recycled your temp bitmap when you no longer need it.

```
package com.example.stack2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class YouAreWelcome extends Activity {

    Bitmap tempBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        class VennView extends View {
            public VennView(Context context) {
                super(context);

            }

            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                if(tempBmp.isRecycled() || tempBmp.getWidth()!=canvas.getWidth() || tempBmp.getHeight()!=canvas.getHeight())
                {
                    tempBmp.recycle();
                    tempBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                    c.setBitmap(tempBmp);
                }

                    //clear previous drawings
                c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);

                int alpha = 255, val = 255;
                int ar = Color.argb(alpha, val, 0, 0);
                int ag = Color.argb(alpha, 0, val, 0);
                int ab = Color.argb(alpha, 0, 0, val);
                float w = canvas.getWidth();
                float h = canvas.getHeight();
                float cx = w / 2f;
                float cy = h / 2;
                float r = w / 5;
                float tx = (float) (r * Math.cos(30 * Math.PI / 180));
                float ty = (float) (r * Math.sin(30 * Math.PI / 180));
                float expand = 1.5f;
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.ADD));
                paint.setColor(ar);
                c.drawCircle(cx, cy - r, expand * r, paint);
                paint.setColor(ag);
                c.drawCircle(cx - tx, cy + ty, expand * r, paint);
                paint.setColor(ab);
                c.drawCircle(cx + tx, cy + ty, expand * r, paint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(tempBmp, 0, 0, null);
            }
        }
        this.setContentView(new VennView(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Pavel; and so quick too!

Comment: BTW, would you know of an alternative to PorterDuff.Mode.ADD that is compatible with SDK version 8? The documentation says that ADD was added in version 8 but it lies. It was really introduced in version 11 and crashes on some older devices that should not have been allowed to install my widget.

Comment: This is great! Can you apply this technique to bitmaps that overlap each other?

Comment: @bot_bot I hope so because I may reimplement my app that way.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks again Pavel. That would have been very difficult for me to have figured out on my own. I am answering my own question to better drill into details, but I've accepted yours as the best answer.

You are right that I prefer not to have to create and manage an off-screen Bitmap (and Canvas). That is essentially why I mentioned that a black or white background would be fine to make this work.

I'm never concerned with performance before I see something working but I share your caution after that point. Editing your version to fix that and remove those members gives the implementation below.

Is this robust? Note the two calls to Canvas.drawColor() which I suspect could also be combined into one.

```
package com.superliminal.android.test.venn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class VennColorsActivity extends Activity {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        class VennView extends View {
            public VennView(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);
                int alpha = 255, val = 255;
                int ar = Color.argb(alpha, val, 0, 0);
                int ag = Color.argb(alpha, 0, val, 0);
                int ab = Color.argb(alpha, 0, 0, val);
                float w = canvas.getWidth();
                float h = canvas.getHeight();
                float cx = w / 2f;
                float cy = h / 2;
                float r = w / 5;
                float tx = (float) (r * Math.cos(30 * Math.PI / 180));
                float ty = (float) (r * Math.sin(30 * Math.PI / 180));
                float expand = 1.5f;
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.ADD));
                paint.setColor(ar);
                canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy - r, expand * r, paint);
                paint.setColor(ag);
                canvas.drawCircle(cx - tx, cy + ty, expand * r, paint);
                paint.setColor(ab);
                canvas.drawCircle(cx + tx, cy + ty, expand * r, paint);
            }
        }
        setContentView(new VennView(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution is also correct. I suggested to use separate bitmap because usually you want to blend only colors you want and not mess up with the rest of UI. The only one comment to your code is that `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);` call is useless since you clear entire area by calling `canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);`. So in theory you can drop this line

Comment: @Melinda Green how can i change paint color of canvas on every button click in my activity so that it can give differnet background colors

Comment: @Erum Hannan Just store a color in the button's onClick method and set that color as background with canvas.drawColor with it in onDraw.

Comment: @MelindaGreen  how can i call onDraw method from main activity ? may i need to pass color argument in onDraw() method

Comment: @Erum Hannan You do not call onDraw, but this is not the place for a discussion. See the documentation for Activity.

Comment: @Erum you shouldn't be calling `View.onDraw(Canvas)`, as @Melinda Green has already pointed out. Instead, you'll have to call `View.invalidate()` to request the UI to invalidate that view. The invalidation process will involve the `View.onDraw(Canvas)` method and you'll achieve what you asked for.